# Create an element once in a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've written quite a few jQuery plugins in the past and this problem has come up a couple times now. Usually I just create a global variable outside the closure and call it a day. This time I'm trying to figure out what the proper way of doing it is.

So here's the deal. I have my base plugin setup like this:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.nameOfPlugin = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        foo: 'foo'
    }
    var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function(){
        //if first time through call create
    });
  };

  function create() {
    //create stuff here only once
    $('body').append("<div id='plugin_overlay'></div>");
  };

})(jQuery);
```

and obviously I would initate it like this:

```
$('.class').nameOfPlugin({foo:'bar'});
```

Since I am using a class as a selector return this.each could run anywhere from 1 to 50 times. What is the best way to run the create method only once per selector?

I realize that in this situation I can simply check:

```
$('#plugin_overlay').length > 0
```

but I will be adding a timestamp at the end of the id so it is unique based on the selector.

I do have a couple more ideas onto what I can do, im just wondering what is the best way to do this.

Comment: I normally attach it to the `.data()` of the element, and then check that. Not sure if there's any downsides to that, but it's always been pretty easy.

Comment: Add a variable to your object and store the new object generated by create (global to the plugin, not the create function itself). Then, when you need it, re-reference that variable (or create when uninitialized)? [Unless I'm misunderstanding]

Comment: @robert yeah I do that as well, just didn't include it in my example. and yeah I'll give that a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be completely misunderstanding the question here, but if you only want to call the method once per selector, why not just call it prior to the each?

```
create();

return this.each(function(){
   ...
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the index parameter which is passed to the each function:

```
return this.each(function(i){
   if(i==0) create();
   ...
});
```

Comment: Wow I am dumb. I was focused on the return this.each forgot I could actually call methods before hand. The first was exactally what I was looking for, Thanks